# Alternate solution to a limit without using L'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{x}{x-a} \left(\frac{x^3}{(a-1)^2}-\frac{a^3}{(x-1)^2}\right)$$

I've gotten to this

$$a \cdot \lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{x^5-2x^4+x^3-a^5+2a^4-a^3}{(x-a)(a-1)^2(x-1)^2}$$

since as far as I'm concerned it's just a matter of doing a long polynomial division between the numerator and $(x-a)$, but I'm getting a remainder that equals infinity despite knowing the answer is finite.

Upon looking up the division itself it seems I had made a mistake, but I'm still curious as to how else this could be solved other than essentially brute forcing it.

Comment: You can see by substitution that $a$ is a root of the numerator so the $x-a$ terms will cancel. Are you counting factoring the numerator as "brute forcing it"?

Comment: Factoring $x^5-a^5$ is brute force lol @Hasse1987

Comment: If you write the numerator as $(x^5 - a^5) -2(x^4 - a^4) + (x^3 - a^3)$ you can see that $(x-a)$ is a factor.

Comment: @Isham polynomial division...

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{x}{x-a} \left(\frac{x^3}{(a-1)^2}-\frac{a^3}{(x-1)^2}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to a}x\left(\dfrac1{(a-1)^2}\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{x^3-a^3}{x-a}+a^3\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{\dfrac1{(a-1)^2}-\dfrac1{(x-1)^2}}{x-a}\right)$$

Now $\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{\dfrac1{(a-1)^2}-\dfrac1{(x-1)^2}}{x-a}$

$=\dfrac1{(a-1)^2}\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac1{(x-1)^2}\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{(x-1)^2-(a-1)^2}{x-a}=?$

Answer (score 0):

One way is to solve with Differentiation From First Principles perspective:

$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{x}{x-a} \left(\frac{x^3}{(a-1)^2}-\frac{a^3}{(x-1)^2}\right)=\lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{x}{x-a} \left(\dfrac{x^3(x-1)^2-a^3 (a-1)^2}{(a-1)^2 (x-1)^2}\right)=\dfrac{a}{(a-1)^4} \left( \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{x^3(x-1)^2-a^3 (a-1)^2}{x-a}  \right)=\dfrac{a}{(a-1)^4}(x^3(x-1)^2)'|_{x=a}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Please give me feedback on my answer.